# Route Hijacking in umbraco 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I'm trying to set up route hijacking on Umbraco 7 with little success.
I have a view called `Home.cshtml`, the top few lines of which are:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}
```

I added a controller:

-EDIT-
updated question to include `Index()` controller action.

```
namespace CLIAUmbraco7.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
    {
        public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
        {
            string country = "";

            return base.Index(model);
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }     
    }
```

Sticking a breakpoint on the `Layout` line catches the site before it loads but `HomeController` is never called. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the controller needs to be called

[TheDocumentType**Alias**YouWantToHijack]Controller

If your document type is not "Home" then it will not be intercepted.

Comment: Yup, this is probably the issue. The [link](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-controllers) I have added to the answer contains this information: *It's easiest to demonstrate with an example : let's say you have a Document Type called 'Home'. You can create a custom locally declared controller in your MVC web project called 'HomeController' and ensure that it inherits from Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController and now all pages that are of document type 'Home' will be routed through your custom controller.*

Comment: The document is a view called `home.cshtml` but in Umbraco the type is shown as `Home Page`.

Comment: Craig is referring the *Document Type* of the page located in *Umbraco* - traverse to your page (Homepage) in CMS and go to properties tab to see what is the name of *Document Type* associated with that node.

Comment: Type is listed as `Home Page`

Comment: Have now set `Document type` to `Home` but still no joy.

Comment: Check the template you `Document Type` is referring to by going to `Home` `Document Type` and looking at the section `Allowed templates`.

Comment: Home is ticked under `Allowed templates`

Comment: Seems a bit odd. From the description you have given it sounds like it should be working. I think it's really the document type *alias* which is used, so if you just changed the document type name make sure the alias also updated. As the link in Marko's comment suggests, having an Index method should catch any associated template.

Comment: Ahh, alias is listed as HomePage.... lemme check... YES! thank you - it's the alias right enough. =)

Comment: Glad that got it - I've updated my answer to clarify it's the alias. Pretty much anything outside of the actual back office content editor uses the aliases as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an `Index()` controller action. Your controller should look like this:

```
public class HomeController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        //Do some stuff here, then return the base method
        return base.Index(model);
    }

}
```

Take a look at the article on [Umbraco website](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/custom-controllers).

Comment: Thanks but with or without `Index()`, the `HomeController` still isn't called before the site loads.

Comment: I've added it to the question.